# Sum of 2 numbers being prime

Tags: java

I am working on a program where given a number say 4, I need to find out the possible ways to use all the numbers from 1 to 4, in such a way that the numbers next to each other sum to a prime number.

For example, if given number is 4, then possible ways are:

```
1 2 3 4
1 4 3 2
```

I am using the below approach, please let me know if there is any simplified approach:

Step 1: Find all prossible combinations of numbers 1 to 4, say

```
1 2 3 4
1 3 2 4
1 3 4 2
2 3 4 1
2 3 1 4
etc
```

Step 2: Find out what series matches the given requirement, and increment a counter. Finally display the value of counter.

Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: Backtracking would make this a lot faster for large numbers. With your approach the number 14 will aready require several minutes to find all solutions.

Comment: Just wondering, what would this ever be useful for?

Comment: It's useful as an exercise.

Comment: @SpiderPig, can you please suggest how it can be done

Comment: Say you do this for 5, as you can rule out 13245, that means you can also rule out 13254, 13425, 13452, 13524 and 13542. So yes, there is a better approach.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable first pass. There are optimisations you could make, like short circuiting rows as soon as you know they won't match. `1 3 ...` won't, for instance, and you can know that without even looking at the other numbers in that row. Then, if you generate the rows such that prefixes are all together (all `1 3 ...`s, for instance), you can skip whole sections as well.

Comment: Additionally, you can also consider that even and odd pairs cannot be placed next to each other because they always sum up to an even number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses backtracking to speed up the program.

```
public class PrimeSum {

  private static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if(n % 2 == 0) return false;
    for(int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
      if(n % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  private static void findSolutions(int[] a, int n) {
    if(n >= a.length) {
      System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(a));
    } else {
      for(int i = n; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(n == 0 || isPrime(a[n - 1] + a[i])) {
          int t = a[n];
          a[n] = a[i];
          a[i] = t;
          findSolutions(a, n + 1);
          t = a[n];
          a[n] = a[i];
          a[i] = t;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      a[i] = i + 1;
    }
    findSolutions(a, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: No explanation to go along with the code? Just "please do my homework for me" -- "ok here you go"? :-\

Comment: Reading the description of `Backtracking` on Wikipedia should explain this sufficiently.

Comment: As one of the commenters above mentioned (ahem), this kind of problem is most useful as an exercise. By doing it for the OP, you're taking away the exercise part. It is now primarily useful for getting a grade. You do you, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

I took a somewhat different approach. First I look at which pairs are allowed. So, when you start with the number 4, you have the following options:

- combine 1 with 2 or 4
- combine 2 with 1 or 3
- combine 3 with 2 or 4
- combine 4 with 1 or 3

What you need to do now is, to start with the potential sequences of two numbers:

- 1,2
- 1,4
- 2,1
- 2,3
- 3,2
- 3,4
- 4,1
- 4,3

After that you just start to extent them. So in the case of the first (1,2), you have the option to add a 1  or a 3, as for 2 the available options are 1 or 3 (see first bullet-list). That gives the sequences 1,2,1 and 1,2,3. As you can't use numbers twice, the first option can be ignored.

That way, you end up with the following sequences of three numbers:

- 1,2,3
- 1,4,3
- 2,1,4
- 2,3,4
- 3,2,1
- 3,2,4
- 3,4,1
- 4,1,2
- 4,3,2

Continue doing this and you end up with the solution:

- 1,2,3,4
- 1,4,3,2
- 2,1,4,3
- 2,3,4,1
- 3,2,1,4
- 3,4,1,2
- 4,1,2,3
- 4,3,2,1

Here is my solution in code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main2 {
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static boolean isPrime(int number) {
        if(number % 2 == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for(int i = 3; i * i <= number; i += 2) {
          if(number % i == 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
      }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Get number from user
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a value");
        int number = scanner.nextInt();

        LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> solutions = new LinkedList<>();

        //Make a HashMap with all the viable combinations using two numbers
        //Make a HashMap with all potential combinations
        HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>> viableCombinations = new HashMap<>();
        LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> potentialSolutions = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= number; j++) {
                if (isPrime(i+j)) {
                    if (viableCombinations.containsKey(i)) {
                        viableCombinations.get(i).add(j);
                    }
                    else {
                        LinkedList<Integer> newCombination = new LinkedList<Integer>();
                        newCombination.add(j);
                        viableCombinations.put(i, newCombination);
                    }
                    if (viableCombinations.containsKey(j)) {
                        viableCombinations.get(j).add(i);
                    }
                    else {
                        LinkedList<Integer> newCombination = new LinkedList<Integer>();
                        newCombination.add(i);
                        viableCombinations.put(j, newCombination);
                    }

                    LinkedList<Integer> combination = new LinkedList<>();
                    combination.add(i);
                    combination.add(j);
                    potentialSolutions.add(combination);
                    combination = new LinkedList<>();
                    combination.add(j);
                    combination.add(i);
                    potentialSolutions.add(combination);
                }
            }
        }

        //Extend HashMap with all viable combinations
        while (potentialSolutions.size() > 0) {
            LinkedList<Integer> potentialSolution = potentialSolutions.pop();
            if (potentialSolution.size() == number) {
                solutions.add(potentialSolution);
            }
            else {
                LinkedList<Integer> combinations = viableCombinations.get(potentialSolution.getLast());
                for (int i = 0; i < combinations.size(); i++) {
                    LinkedList<Integer> newPotentialSolution = new LinkedList<>(potentialSolution);
                    if (!newPotentialSolution.contains(combinations.get(i))) {
                        newPotentialSolution.add(combinations.get(i));
                        potentialSolutions.add(newPotentialSolution);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println(solutions);
    }
}
```